# Load directory in Zeit Now Serverless Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, serverless, vercel

I am building a Zeit Now Serverless Function that will serve an Apple Wallet Pass using the [pass-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@walletpass/pass-js) library. I pass is a folder like this:

```js
const template = await passkit.Template.load(
 path.resolve("pages/api/template/")
);
```

It works great in local development but I get the ENOENT error on the server:

```
2020-01-30T20:57:54.878Z    c40c9174-8e91-4f24-89ca-e53ab5b360ea    ERROR    [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/var/task/pages/api/template'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: '/var/task/pages/api/template'
}
```

I've tried to add `IncludeFiles` configuration to the `now.json` file but it didn't help.

```
"functions": {
    "pages/api/wallet.js": {
      "includeFiles": "template/**"
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Make sure you use `__dirname` as well: `path.resolve(__dirname + "pages/api/template/")`

Comment: `__dirname` equals to `/`, and it results in `[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/pages/api/template']`, both on local development and on the server.

Comment: @RobertWolf could u find the answer? I'm having trouble with the same issue

Comment: @RobertWolf could you find a solution for this error?

Comment: Or you @AxelSchenkelman could find a solution?